# Converting strings to Object types in runtime

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class, something simple like

```
class Example
{
    uint id;
    ushort value1;
    string value2;
    DateTime timestamp;
 }
```

I also have a csv, like:

```
id;value1;value2;timestamp
5;0x2313;whatever;2012-12-23-12:14:34,567
6;0x2A14;something;2012-12-24:13:14:15:167
```

I would like to create objects based on the CSV, however the *real* class is a lot bigger and prone to change, so I would like to use reflection.
I have some code getting the names of Properties and finding the corresponding string. What I don't get is, how I can convert the string to whatever type the Property is. I have found some code samples how to CAST the values, but casting a string to short is not what looks like a solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should take a look at `LINQToCSV`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`Convert.ChangeType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx) method:

```
myObject.Field = Convert.ChangeType(value, fieldType);
```

Comment: well I kind of missed this function, thank you for pointing in out

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bds4fye2.aspx) class.
If you know the type to which you want to convert the string, you can use that.

Or, you can use the type's Parse() or TryParse() methods.

For example, to convert a string to a short you can use [Int16.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hh1awhy.aspx)